# Regex working in text editor(sublime) but not in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I want to extract the line using regex.
The line that I want to extract from document is:

```
":method":"POST",":path":"/api/browser/projects/8bd4d1d3-0b69-515e-8e15-e9c49992f7d5/buckets/b-ao-mock-testing/copy
```

The regex I am using is:

```
":method"[:"a-z,/\d-]{20,1000}/copy
```

The code for the same in python is:

```
re.findall('":method"[:"a-z,/\d-]{20,1000}/copy', str(s), re.MULTILINE)
```

It is working perfectly fine in sublime text but not in python. It is returning an empty list in python. How to resolve this?

Comment: By default, the regex search in Sublime text is case insensitive. You need to turn on `Aa` button to make it case sensitive. In Python, you just used a different regex, without `re.I`. Use `re.I`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])`.
Without this how will `POST` match?

or use `":method"[:"a-zA-Z,/\d-]{20,1000}/copy`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgWw3V/1)